# I need to create a pdf and write into it from a list using c# but not use any third party document nor ITextSharp.Just plain and simple C# code

Tags: pdf

I need to create an excel file and write into it from a list of objects and convert the excel into a pdf using c# but not use any third party document nor ITextSharp. Just plain and simple C# code. No other components.

Comment: So you want to rewrite iTextSharp and an Excel writer all by yourself? Good luck.

Comment: If you use libraries you could probably have this done in a week. Without libraries...I have no idea. Much, much longer.

Comment: Have fun... those will be some interesting years. Of course, if your requirements are very well defined and very simple in design, there may be shortcuts. In that case, though, you have to describe your requirements in sufficient detail.

Answer (score 5):

You don't want to do this.  Here's why: PDF is a non-trivial file format.  Yes, you can sit down with the spec and come up with an understanding and let's assume that you are as efficient and clever an engineer as me (I work on PDF tools for a living and worked on Acrobat).  It will take you at least two to three **months** working full-time to have the infrastructure to create decently rich PDFs in a way that is reliable and maintainable.  Let's say that you're not as good an engineer as me.  It will likely take you the **same three months** to create tools to generate PDF and the tools will be hard to maintain, hard to extend for future needs, and likely will generate incorrect PDF that Acrobat and my tools are expected to accept and interpret in a meaningful way.

Maybe your project has dictated "NO THIRD PARTY ASSEMBLIES." If so, you might want to explain the cost of your time (and future time) and why it's not so bad to have a third party library.  I can tell you right now that the [tools I build](http://www.atalasoft.com/products/dotpdf) aren't cheap, until you consider that the time it will take you to go from download to a generated PDF document will be somewhere between a couple hours and a couple days, depending on how complex your needs are and you will not need to know the PDF spec.

But if you choose to go this route, be sure to download the PDF spec from Adobe and make sure that you read section 14.3.3 about the Document Information Dictionary, and make sure that you fill in the Producer section in every document you generate, because whenever I find PDF files that are wildly out of spec, that's the first place I look to find out who was responsible and I make note and promise to curse loudly and question your parentage (fair's fair - if you use our tools and find that my code has generated a bad PDF, you're free to do the same and I invite you to contact our support line so we can make it right).

Answer (score 1):

There is an open source library called [PDF Sharp](http://www.pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/)

About the excel file, just use an open source file format for it.